# File diff viewer visualizing historical data

Tags: windows, gui, ubuntu, diff, scripting

I have a folder full of textfiles

```
savestate-1.xml
savestate-2.xml
savestate-5.xml
savestate-500.xml
```

which represent how a single file, in this case `savestate.xml`, changed over time. I.e. a full dump of the file at the timestamps 1,2,5,500...

I use KDiff to visualize the differences between two files. But if I want to see how the file evolved over time, it is cumbersome to manually compare file 1 with 2, 2 with 3, ...

Can you recommend a tool/script/technique with a graphical interface to make this easier? E.g. a tool with a timeline or a tool visualizing a "commit" history like gitk?

P.S.: If there is no such tool, I would write a script which basically creates a new git repository, stores the different file states as different commits of the same file and then shows gitk. But I was wondering if there is already a ready-to-go solution